# Weird, the payment form container class can't be overwritten

Tags: magento

I tried to overwrite the **Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container** class with this code:

```
<blocks>
    <module>
        <class>NS_Module_Block</class>
    </module>
    <payment>
        <rewrite>
            <form_container>NS_Module_Block_Payment_Form_Container</form_container>
        </rewrite>
    </payment>
</blocks>
```

Then in app/code/community/NS/Module/Block/Payment/Form/Container.php I simply write this code:

```
class NS_Module_Block_Payment_Form_Container extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container {
    public function getMethods() {
      echo 'hi';die;
    }
}
```

Then I access the onepage checkout, but this code never get executed. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to modify the `one-page checkout form`, you must override the proper block, because the `instance` of `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container` is not called directly, therefor it wont be overridden from a direct rewrite.

The class that needs to be overridden is `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods` since it ultimately extends `Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container` and is the class that actually gets invoked.  So your rewrite needs to read:

Your `config.cml` file should contain

```
<global>
      <blocks>
        <checkout>
         <rewrite>
           <onepage_payment_methods>MyCompany_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods</onepage_payment_methods>
         </rewrite>
        </checkout>
       </blocks>
     </global>
```

and your class declared as:

```
class MyCompany_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods
{

     //do your stuff here

}
```

Let me know if you have any query